# Filter MySQLi with checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

At the moment, I have a page that is displaying some posts. News posts, blog posts etc. What I want to achieve is having checkboxes so the user can check off, whatever kind of post he/she wants to see.

I should for instance be able to check off ´news´ and ´talking points´ and only see posts with those categories, and not see posts with the category ´blog´ for instance.

My current query looks like this (gets all posts, no matter the category). I believe some jQuery should be involved but I am not sure. How can I connect checkboxes with the query?

Can anyone help me with this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC";
```

**EDIT**

I have tried this, but whenever I use the checkboxes, nothing is shown but I do not get an error?

My code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
$categories = $_POST['check_list'];
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($categories as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}
}
}
?>
<br /><br />
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC WHERE `category` IN (".implode(',',$categories).")";
} else {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each checkbox should have a value. When you submit your form (probably a $_POST) you will see on the backend which checkboxes are checked. You can inspire from this tutorial: https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/

**IMPORTANT** - You should filter the form data before using it in your SQL query. You can inspire from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

And you should prepare the variable before using it in the SQL Query:

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"];
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);
```

Now that you know which checkboxes are checked, you need to change the SQL query in order to filter by them.

So I suppose the checkboxes values are numbers (representing id's). So you will have an array called **$ids** that will contain all the checked checkboxes. Your mysql query will become something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE `id_category` IN (".implode(',',$ids).") ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks for your observation. I suppose that he will filter the $_POST variabes bwfore using them. I haven't posted any example where I use dirrectly $_POST['var']..so your comment is pointless.

Comment: Don't mention it. JFYI: whatever "filtering" has absolutely nothing to do with SQL injections

Comment: @Pascut I have added your code but it just stops showing any posts, when I use the checkboxes?

Comment: I get this `Unknown column 'article' in 'where clause'` even though article is amongst one of the categories in the database?

Comment: From your error "Unknown column 'article' in 'where clause'" I can say that you used wrong SQL query. Please try to use "articles" instead of "article". Because the column "article" doesn't exist.